# Is it possible to make a UIView to splash screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

Is it possible to make a UIViewController or UIView type class as a splash screen ? Basically I want an animated splash screen for my app.

Comment: you can use a .xib as a splash screen as of iOS 8

Comment: Yes but when I am assign any class to .xib file its gives me error.

Comment: its showing "launch screen may not use instances of " this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it.

```
 1. First create any UIViewController or UIView
 2. Click project Targets(Click your project-Left side->It shows Project and Targets options)
 3. Click General
 4. Select App Icons and Launch Images
 5. Choose Launch Screen File
 6. Click Drop Down of Launch Screen File
 7. Then Choose your required view controller which sets as splash screen
```

Comment: thanks @user3182143 I just did the same ,now its working

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to make any Viewcontroller as a Splash screen.

Take your ViewController as a initial view then implement one method and call it with method :

[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethodName) withObject:yourObject afterDelay:duration];

then in your Method you can navigate to next ViewController.

Comment: Default viewcontroller.m is my initial ViewController but its still showing the LaunchScreen.xib at the beginning

Comment: Give black background color to LaunchScreen and then your ViewController will come there, you can show it for some duration and then navigate to other view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I got the solution, just change the Launch Screen File from Launchscreen.xib to Main.stroryboard under target. Now it's working.

Comment: if you want to perform any action then you need to create custom splash view like i explain you.