# Use LaunchScreen ViewController instead of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've implemented in my code LaunchScreen as view controller in storyboard and its class is : `LaunchViewController` also its the initial view controller in storyboard.

I set in the project settings the Launch Screen file is : `Main.storyboard`.

Actually i don't want to use Launch screen image, just a controller acts like Launch screen, and I'm getting the following warning in Xcode:

```
 Applications using launch screen files and targeting iOS 7.1 and earlier need to also include a launch image in an asset catalog.
```

How do i solve this warning without using Images, because if i set the launch images in project settings it will automatically show empty screen, then go to my launch screen controller which doesn't make since ?

Comment: I guess you didn't change deployment target. Make deployment target as 9.0

Comment: I'm supporting iOS 7  , any other way ?

Comment: @NataMio  No, you can't

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296575/is-it-possible-to-make-a-uiview-to-splash-screen/33296777#33296777

Answer (score 0):

For supporting iOS 7.1 and earlier you must to add static generated images.

Comment: LaunchViewController has a view in storyboard and its initial, what you just said doesn't solve anything !

Comment: kirander, does it's mean we must provide both, static generated images AND storyboard ?

Comment: loki, yes. you must have both

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the Launch screen image and delete all launch images from the attribute inspector and uncheck it all.